# Mother of Sita in Ramayana

Tags: ramayana, sita

In  Valmiki Ramayana, at several places Sita's mother (referred to wife of Seeradhwaja Janaka) is mentioned, but nowhere her name. In any other Purana, name of Sita's mother is mentioned? If so, where and what it is?

Comment: Sita was born of the earth. King Janaka's wife was not Sita's natural mother.

Comment: My query is not her natural mother. Mother who brought up her. When Seeradhwaja Janaka is mentioned as her father, naturally his wife is her mother who brought up her

Answer (score 8):

According to [Tulasidas's Ramacharitamanasa, Balakanda, 1.324](https://archive.org/stream/RamcharitmanasGitapressEnglish/Ramcharitmanas%20Gitapress%20English#page/n327/search/sunayana), name of the wife of King Janaka was Sunayana.

> जनक पाटमहिषी जग जानी। सीय मातु किमि जाइ बखानी।। 
>   सुजसु सुकृत सुख सुदंरताई। सब समेटि बिधि रची बनाई।।
>   समउ जानि मुनिबरन्ह बोलाई। सुनत सुआसिनि सादर ल्याई।। 
>   **जनक बाम दिसि सोह सुनयना। हिमगिरि संग बनि जनु मयना।।**
>   कनक कलस मनि कोपर रूरे। सुचि सुंगध मंगल जल पूरे।। 
>   निज कर मुदित रायँ अरु रानी। धरे राम के आगें आनी।।
>   पढ़हिं बेद मुनि मंगल बानी। गगन सुमन झरि अवसरु जानी।। 
>   बरु बिलोकि दंपति अनुरागे। पाय पुनीत पखारन लागे।।
>
> What words can describe the world-renowned queen-consort of Janaka and Sita's 
>   mother? The Creator had exhausted in fashioning her all the bright glory, virtue, joy and 
>   beauty. Perceiving the appropriate time, the great sages sent for her; and in response to 
>   their call married women whose hasbands were alive brought her with due honour. **Queen 
>   Sunayana shone forth to Janaka's left even as Maina beside Himavan (the mountain- 
>   king)**. The king and queen joyfully brought and placed with their own hands gold vases 
>   and beautiful trays of jewels filled with holy, scented and auspicious water before Sri 
>   Rama. The sages recited the Veda in joyous tones and at the proper time flowers rained 
>   down from the heavens. The royal couple were enraptured to behold the Bridegroom and 
>   began to wash His holy feet.

BTW, mother Sita is said to be the daughter of mother Earth but technically, Sunayana can be said to be her mother.

Comment: The problem is that Valmiki's and Tualsida's Ramayana's vary in many respects. You cannot use Tualsida's recension as a 'proof' for Valmiki. To point out one glaring difference, in Valmiki, Rama is a Kshatriya. In Tulisida's Ramayana Rama is a Brahmin.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Thanks for your comment. However, I know that there is a huge difference in Valmiki Ramayana and Ramcharitamanasa but I don't think your example is right. In Ramacharitamanasa, Sri Rama is Kshatriya too as mentioned by Bharata in Ayodhya Kanda, Doha 229: `“A Ksatriya (warrior) by caste and born in the race of Raghu I am known 
throughout the world as a servant of Sri Rama (yourself).”` And also the question was `In any other Purana, name of Sita's mother is mentioned?` It was not strictly to Valmiki Ramayana.

Comment: Satisfied with the answer from Sri Triyugi Narayana Mani. Charitham Raghunathasya Shatakoti pravistaram. Probably, now available is only a glimpse. Tulsidas must have got it somewhere or even in dream. When there is no contradicting version anywhere, we will have to accept it. Thanks for answer and connecting link

Comment: @B.Chandrashekara If you're satisfied with this answer, you can accept it by clicking on the tick mark (✓) below the voting buttons.

Answer (score 2):

Her mother was *Yogini* as written in [Shiva purana.](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226066.html)

> धन्या प्रिया द्वितीया तु योगिनी जनकस्य च।
>   तस्या कन्या महालक्ष्मीर्नाम्ना सीता भविष्यति।।
>
> 29. The second daughter Dhanyā shall **be the Yoginī**, the wife of Janaka. Her daughter shall be Mahālakṣmī in the name of **Sītā**.